# What is AELWriter?

Tags: macos

What is AELWriter? It's in my daemons and appears to be from Apple. What does it do? Is it part of Yosemite? Or something else? How can you tell?

I'm just a lifelong Mac user lost and confused amongst the arcane and cryptic names. Why they ever went away from plain English names for things, like they had in System 9 and earlier, is beyond me.

Comment: + for arcane and cryptic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a component of Apple's "Pro" apps (Logic, Aperture etc.). [Here](http://audioperception.com/knowledge-base/48-apple-logic/1638-pro-applications-entering-serial-number-after-migrating-causes-the-application-to-stop-responding)'s what you want to know (hopefully), links to a knowledgebase regarding issues with Apple Pro apps following system migration...

And [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/TS3519)'s more from mothership Apple...